# Simple Master/Detail scenario with combobox/datagrid in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

I'm building a series of admin forms as part of my application.

Many of the forms have this same scenario, and I'm wondering what the best way to manage this is...

[Here's a screenshot of an example from the old winforms app.](http://gyazo.com/6cc16dbb76f831fc382c7721d71fdde2.png) Not all of the forms are this simple, but I figure it's a good place to start.

The first field is always a combo box. After a user selects an item, the other fields populate with the associated data.

Currently, my ViewModel contains an `ObservableCollection<circuit>` (for this example). I'm not sure how to set up my bindings, given the master/detail scenario where your master (primary combobox) is also part of your detail (CircuitName field). I was thinking of pulling the combobox out and, after selecting an item, displaying a datagrid. Is there a better way? If I do go this route, I have read a few articles that indicate binding a combobox INSIDE the datagrid, while property binding the selectedValue prop is a total PITA. Obviously having a combobox would be required for a user to create/edit an existing CircuitName...

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but if I was using MVVM Light, like I think you are:)  And I wanted to replicated the screen above I would do something like this.  But I'm probably not 100% understanding what you mean.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Circuit Name"/>
        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCircuit,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Circuits}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Circuit Code"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCircuit.Code}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Voltage"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCircuit.Voltage}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Okay"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel"></Button>

</Grid>
```

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using MvvmLight1.Model;

namespace MvvmLight1.ViewModel
{

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Circuits = new ObservableCollection<Circuit>
                       {
                           new Circuit {Code = "123123", Name = "Test1", Voltage = 2.2, Id = 1},
                           new Circuit {Code = "14224", Name = "Test2", Voltage = 3.2, Id = 2},
                           new Circuit {Code = "54234", Name = "Test3", Voltage = 4.2, Id = 3},
                       };

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Circuit> Circuits { get; set; }

    private Circuit _selectedCircuit;
    public Circuit SelectedCircuit
    {
        get { return _selectedCircuit; }
        set { _selectedCircuit = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCircuit");
        }
    }
}
```

}

namespace MvvmLight1.Model
{

```
public class Circuit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public double Voltage { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: Although I found the answer on my own (And it was exactly the same as yours, except obvious differences in how our data is populated!), I'll give it to you for putting in so much effort :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was really simple actually.

I have my `ObservableCollection<Circuit> Circuits` that's loaded in the VM Constructor. I created a `ObservableCollection<Circuit> SelectedCircuit`. My xaml then looks like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Configs}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedConfig, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="SwitchCode"
                 />
<toolkit:DataForm CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedConfig}" AutoEdit="False"  />
```